# Retrieve number of search results from Google API

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I was looking for the number of search results from Google and found some topics on Stackoverflow, however, I couldn't find anything in the Custom Search API provided by Google. Did they even drop the 100 requests per day feature or can anyone provide the exact link with the respective Java object/code sample/...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100 free requests limit [is still in effect for the API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#Pricing) and this appears to be the [main page](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/terms?hl=en) for resources but asking for external links beyond this is offtopic - just ask another question if you get stuck part way through coding.